# Extends state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extends

I need to inherit the state. Can I inherit the state? When I do this, I get an empty state.

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
      this.state = {
        param1: 
      };
  }
 ...
}

class Example2 extends Example {
  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.param1} // empty
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: All the answers have one meaning, but this solution did not suit me

Answer (score 7):

You can extend state as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    ...this.state,
    extraStuff: '',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using inheritance, you could use regular composition and pass the entire `Example` state as props to `Example2` and use the props passed to `Example2` as initial state.

**Example**

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    param1: "test"
  };

  render() {
    return <Example2 {...this.state} />;
  }
}

class Example2 extends React.Component {
  state = {...this.props};

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
      this.state = {
        param1: "param1"
      };
  }
  render() {
  const { param1 } = this.state;
  return (
  <Example2 param1={param1} />
 )
 }
}   

class Example2 extends Example {
  render() {
    const { param1 } = this.props;
    return (
      {param1} 
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kovich. You can pass the state of one component to another only as props like this code:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
      this.state = {
        param1: 
      };
  }

render(){

return (<Example2 param1 ={this.state.param1} />)
}

 ...
}

class Example2 extends Example {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
      this.state = {
        param1: this.props.param1
      };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.param1} // empty
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance is not really supported in React, you can find more information on this link:

> https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

What you can do is to have a global state manager (for example Redux) or pass the state to the `Example2` component on the following way:

```
class Example extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      param1: 'test'
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <Example2 state={this.state} />
    );   
  } 
}
```

After that you will be able to reach it in `Example2` by `this.props.state.param1`.